# A readdir() issue

Tags: c, linux, readdir

My intention is to read every directory and file rooted at a directory given as input in a depth-first manner and towards it I had written a portion(very very initial) of code as shown below.

```
int main()
{

 DIR *fd_dir;
 struct dirent *s_dirent;
 struct stat buff;
 char str[100];

 fd_dir = opendir("/home/juggler");
 if(fd_dir == 0)
    printf("Error opening directory");

 while((s_dirent = readdir(fd_dir)) != NULL)
 {
    printf("\n Name %s",s_dirent->d_name);

 } 
 closedir(fd_dir);
}
```

Now, the directory juggler has 3 directories say A, B and C but an output to this program not only gives these three directories but also .mozilla .zshrc .gvfs .local .bash_history etc which i do not see when opening juggler normally.

What are these extra things inside juggler and how do I not read them

Thanks

Comment: Use `nftw` to recurse trough directory trees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Unix world, to hide files, you make the first character a `.`. So when you simply `ls` in a directory, you don't see them. You have to use `ls -a` or `ls -A` to see them.

You can't "ignore them". You can check in your loop to see if the first character is a `.` and `continue`.

```
if ('.' == s_dirent->d_name[0]) {
    continue;
}
```

But keep in mind that they are all equal citizens. **So there is no reason to skip them**. What you might *want* to skip are the special files `.` (current directory) and `..` (parent directory).

Comment: @cnicular Thanks...but what are these files

Comment: @Juggler You can `vim` / `cd` into most of them. They are generally configuration files that most users don't want to see. For instance, `.bash_history` records the history of your commands. `.zshrc` is sourced by interactive `zsh` shells, `.mozilla` is probably a directory used by firefox et all etc. So they are **useful, needed, real** files. It's just that you don't generally operate directly on them, so they're "out of sight".